# How to search for a string containing "PRODUCT_VARIANT_NAMES" from a makefile present in specific path & store in array using shell script

Tags: shell

> I am new or beginner to shell script.
> How to search for a string containing "PRODUCT_VARIANT_NAMES" from a makefile > > present in specific path and store all the values assigned to it in an array
> [array name is PRODUCT_VARIANT_ARRAY_LIST].
> For example, say mmhp.mk is the make file present in some path device\pro\mmh4p.mk & it has content as shown below:

### mmh4p.mk

1.flnslndddsa
2.fssd
3.dasdsa
4.dsadsa
5.PRODUCT_VARIANT_NAMES :=
6.    mmh4p_fgn.SKT_KR 
7.    mmh4p_fgn.KT_KR 
8.    mmh4p_fgn.OPEN_KR 
9.    mmh4p-pr_fne.OPEN_EU_DS 
10.   mmh4p_fne.OPEN_EU_DS
11.bdn;lkndlak;ns;lndnlsnkl
12.dsland;lsandd
13.dlamsdlmasd
14.ndlbadnsad
15. ;asmdsamd,

> How to write a script to grep all the values from
> "PRODUCT_VARIANT_NAMES :=" & store it in an array
> PRODUCT_VARIANT_ARRAY_LIST should contain the values
> `mmh4p_fgn.SKT_KR`, `mmh4p_fgn.KT_KR`, `mmh4p_fgn.OPEN_KR`,
> `mmh4p-pr_fne.OPEN_EU_DS`, `mmh4p_fne.OPEN_EU_DS`
>
> Note: The string "PRODUCT_VARIANT_NAMES :=" can defined in single line as below

```
PRODUCT_VARIANT_NAMES := mmh4p_fgn.SKT_KR mmh4p_fgn.KT_KR mmh4p_fgn.OPEN_KR mmh4p-pr_fne.OPEN_EU_DS mmh4p_fne.OPEN_EU_DS
```

or it can be multiple lines ending with back slash as shown above.

Comment: Unless there are always five `PRODUCT_VARIANT_NAMES` you need to store, you will need to show a complete makefile so we know what comes after the names to know when to stop adding to the array.

Comment: Complete make file content is as below:
---------------------------------------------------
flnslndddsa
fssd
dasdsa
dsadsa
PRODUCT_VARIANT_NAMES :=
    mmh4p_fgn.SKT_KR \
    mmh4p_fgn.KT_KR \
    mmh4p_fgn.OPEN_KR \
    mmh4p-pr_fne.OPEN_EU_DS \
   mmh4p_fne.OPEN_EU_DS

flnslndddsa
fssd
dasdsa
dsadsa

Comment: That's not that helpful, I doubt there is a `finslndddsa` in the file -- but if all names after `PRODUCT_VARIANT_NAMES := mmh4p_fgn.SKT_KR ` start with the prefix `mmh4p` and that (whatever it may be) is consistent for the prefix for the names you want to capture in an array, you can take the first name after `:=` and isolate everything before the `'_'` in say `prefix` and then do `array=($(grep "$prefix" filename))` to capture all of the strings that begin with `$prefix` in `array`.